# RTF content causes SQL Server CONCAT to fail

Tags: sql-server, linux, rtf, sqlcmd

I have a large SQL Server database and one of the columns may contain RTF formated text. In order to generate a CSV, I'm using string concatenation to insert Quotes around the column content.

However, for some rows, concatenation simply fails and the final quote is not inserted.

I'm using the free version of SQL Server for Linux, on a Ubuntu 16.04.

This is one example of the SQL query:

```
SELECT '"' + CAST([deTexto] as NVARCHAR(4000)) + '"' FROM DIGITALIZACAO
```

Which results in (modified):

```
"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1046\f0\fs16 \f1\'e1ria : \'e7a  l\' de \'e7\'e3o da  \par
\par
\par
\par
x xxstx\'x7x Fxxxrxl xx xxrxb\'x1 pxblxcxx xstx sxxxnx x sxntxn\'x7x xx x\'x7\'x3x xxvxxx pxlx xxprxsx Vxlx cxntrx tr\'xxs pxssxxs xnvxlvxxxs nx xnvxs\'x3x xx xstrxxx xx Fxrrx Cxrxx\'x1s. x fxrrxvxx fxx xntxrxxtxxx pxr gxrxxpxxrxs lxgxxxs xx xTx (xxvxxxntx xxs Trxbxlhxxxrxs xx xxnxrx\'x7\'x3x) x xntxgrxntxs xx xST (xxvxxxntx xx Trxbxlhxxxrxs Sxx-Txrrx), xx xbrxl xxstx xnx.\pxr
x xxxz Cxrlxs Hxnrxqxx Bxrlxxx Hxxxxx cxnxxnxx xs r\'x9xs Lxxs Sxlxx\'x9 xx Frxn\'x7x, xrxvxl Cxrvxlhx xxrtxns x Rxxxxnxx Bxnxgnx xxrxxrx pxr txrxx xxscxxprxxx xxcxs\'x3x xx xxstx\'x7x, qxx prxxbxx x xntxrxx\'x7\'x3x xx fxrrxvxx. xlxs xxvxr\'x3x xfxtxxr x pxgxxxntx xxs pxrxxs x xxnxs sxfrxxxs pxlx xxprxsx, nx vxlxr xx, nx prxzx xx 15 xxxs. xlxs txxb\'x9x fxrxx cxnxxnxxxs xx pxgxxxntx xx \'x0 Vxlx, x t\'xxtxlx xx vxrbx xxvxcxt\'xxcxx.\pxr
x Vxlx xxvxx x\'x7\'x3x cxntrx Rxxxxnxx Bxnxgnx xxrxxrx, xxrxnxxr Fxrrxxrx xx xrx\'fxxx, Lxxs Sxlxx\'x9 xx Frxn\'x7x, xnt\'f4nxx Bxrrxs xx Sxlvx, xlxxxnxrx Rxxrxgxxs, xrxvxl Cxrvxlhx xxrtxns, xtxc\'xxlxx Rxxrxgxxs Rxchx, Frxncxscx xxs Chxgxs xxxrx, xtxvxlxx xx Crxz xrxntxs, xxrxlxnx xxchxxx xxs Sxntxs x xxtrxs, pxrx qxx sxgxnxx x xxcxxxntx, \lxblqxxtx xbstxnhxx-sx xx pr\'x1txcx xx xtxs qxx pxssxx xxfxcxltxr, xxpxxxr, txrbxr xx xsbxlhxr x pxssx xxxrcxxx sxbrx x xstrxxx xx Fxrrx Cxrxx\'x1s x sxx fxxxx xx xxx\'xxnxx, xxplxrxxx pxlx xxtxrx xx vxrtxxx xx cxncxss\'x3x xxxx pxlx xnx\'x3x\rxblqxxtx . \pxr
Txxb\'x9x sxgxnxx x xxcxxxntx, x Vxlx txr\'x1 xx pxgxr hxnxr\'x1rxxs xxvxcxt\'xxcxxs x xxrxlxnx xxchxxx xxs Sxntxs, nx vxlxr xx R$1.000. xlx fxx x \'fxnxcx r\'x9 cxtxxx nx x\'x7\'x3x qxx xfxrxcxx xxfxsx x cxnsxgxxx xbtxr x xlxgxtxxxxxxx pxrx x cxxsx. Sxgxnxx xs xxtxs xx x\'x7\'x3x, n\'x3x h\'x1 nxxx qxx x vxncxlx \'x0 xbstrx\'x7\'x3x xx xstrxxx xx Fxrrx Cxrxx\'x1s.\pxr
x r\'x9x xtxc\'xxlxx Rxxrxgxxs Rxchx txxb\'x9x cxnsxgxxx xbtxr x xlxgxtxxxxxxx pxrx x cxxsx, pxxs xxsxx xlx sxnxx prxsxxxntx xx xxx cxxpxrxtxvx, n\'x3x sx xxxxnstrxx, nx pxtx\'x7\'x3x xnxcxxl, qxx xlx xx x cxxpxrxtxvx xxsxxpxnhxrxx xtxvxxxxxs qxx vxxlxrxx x pxssx xx Vxlx. (Pxrtxl xRx) \pxr
\f0\par
}
```

On my terminal screen, it also prints lots of white spaces and 2 line breaks after the text.

As it can be seen, the final quote is missing. This behavior occurs only in RTF fields. I guess some special character is breaking the concatenation function, but I can see no warnings.

I would like some help in finding out who is breaking the concatenation function in order to replace it.

Comment: Is it because your total characters ends up being larger than 4,000 characters?

Comment: If I cast it to NVARCHAR(2359), the same error occurs. If I cast it to NVARCHAR(2358), the ending quote appears and the text remains complete. So, there is a character in this position messing everything. How can I find out who it is? It appears only as a white space...

Comment: Put an RTRIM() around the text and see if that removes the bad character at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately not... Rtrim removes white spaces, but it seems that it is no the case